# String swap by swap function

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have written code to swap strings, but I am not able to swap. What is the problem and how can I solve it by using a function, `swap`?

```
#include <stdio.h>

void swap( char*,char*);
int main()
{
    char *ptr[2] = {"hello", "morning"};
    swap(ptr[0], ptr[1]);
    printf("%s %s", ptr[0], ptr[1]);
    return 0;
}

void swap(char *t1, char*t2)
{
    char *t;
    t = t1;

    t1 = t2;
    t2 = t;
}
```

I also tried to pass `(&ptr[0], &ptr[1])`, but here it shows a [`segmentation fault`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Segmentation_fault). Also I made a char, `*p1 = ptr[0], char *p1 =  ptr[1]`, and then passes `&p1`, and `&p2` to `swap`, but still I get a segmentation fault.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

C function arguments are pass-by-value. You're passing the value of addresses to your `swap` function, and expecting those values, the addresses, to change. But only the *copies* of the addresses in your `swap` function change.

To change the actual passed-in addressed, you'll need an aditional level of reference:

```
void swap(char **t1, char **t2)
{
    char *t;

    t = *t1;
    *t1= *t2;
    *t2 = t;
}
```

And call this `swap` like so: `swap(&ptr[0], &ptr[1]);`

Answer (score 6):

You need to pass in pointers to the pointers of the char arrays in order to switch them. By doing that you can swap the values of those pointers instead. (Which are the actual arrays.)

```
#include<stdio.h>
void swap( char**,char**);
int main()
{
        char *ptr[2] = {"hello","mornig"};
        swap(&ptr[0], &ptr[1]);
        printf("%s %s",ptr[0], ptr[1]);
        return 0;
}

void swap( char **t1,char **t2)
{
        char *t;
        t = *t1;

        *t1 = *t2;
        *t2 =t;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass pointers to your strings to swap them (char**). Otherwise the changes you do will be local to the swap function.

```
void swap( char **t1,char **t2)
{
        char *t;
        t = *t1;

        *t1 = *t2;
        *t2 =t;
}

int main()
{
        char *ptr[2] = {"hello","mornig"};
        swap(&ptr[0], &ptr[1]);
        printf("%s %s",ptr[0],ptr[1]);
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`char *ptr[2] = {"hello","mornig"};` - This statement means you are allocating an array of size 2 which is going to store a address of two strings(ie `char *`). Now the two strings you are giving will be in `text segment` which is a read only data. If we tries to modify it, which will leads to crash(sgmentation fault).

So if you call `swap(&ptr[0], &ptr[1])` leads to a crash. because you are trying to write the charcter `m` in the first read only string `h`. Write is not possible to the string which is in `text segment`.

If you want to simply swap a string you can call the function as `swap(&ptr[0], &ptr[1])`, which is equivalent to `swap((ptr + 0),(ptr + 1));`.

And change the swap function as below

```
void swap( char **t1,char **t2)
{
        char *t;

        t = *t1;
        *t1 = *t2;
        *t2 =t;
}
```

Here we are just swapping the address of the string stored in the array pointer `ptr`.